# How to write QueryBuilder Query for update Collections(Set) in Cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I want to write QueryBuilder query for the following CQL command in java.

```
UPDATE category_utility
      SET imageurls = imageurls + {'http://image1.jpg','http://image2.jpg','http://image3.jpg'} WHERE category_title = 'cat1';
```

In **JAVA**, I try with this following. I do not know how to write **add** in set operation in QueryBuilder command .

```
public void  addImageList(ArrayList<String> list, int categoryId) {
    Statement = QueryBuilder.update("category_utility").with(QueryBuilder.set("imageurls", list.toString())).where(QueryBuilder.eq("img_category_id", categoryId));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `QueryBuilder.addAll(String, Set<?>)`, but that method takes a `Set` as a parameter, not an `ArrayList`.

So you need to modify your method as follows:

```
public Statement addImages(Set<String> imageurls, int categoryId){
    return QueryBuilder.update("category_utility")
            .with(QueryBuilder.addAll("imageurls", imageurls))
            .where(QueryBuilder.eq("img_category_id", categoryId));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [QueryBuilder](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/querybuilder/QueryBuilder.html) class there are add, addAll and remove, removeAll methods for handling set updates.